# Visual Studio pre-build scripts can't find exe files in windows/system32

Tags: visual-studio, events, command, prompt

I'm stumped. All of a sudden Visual Studio cannot find exe files in the Windows/System32 directory (such as *xcopy*, *attrib* etc).

I have some pre-build and post-build events that execute batch files that use xcopy and attrib. Previously they were working fine but today, during the build process, Visual Studio cannot find them. The error is shown: *'xcopy' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file*.

When I first noticed the problem I tried running xcopy in a regular cmd prompt and the same problem occurred. After I restarted my computer, the problem disappeared in the regular cmd prompt but remained in Visual Studio. After the reboot, the problem does not occur in the Visual Studio cmd prompt either - only from within Visual Studio itself.

Everything appears normal if within one of the batch files I execute *set* to check the PATH variable or *echo %systemroot%*.

In the Tools->Options menu there are settings for VisualC++ directories. However I am running C#, not C++, and besides, I never changed these settings and they appear to be correct.

Anyone had this problem before? Thoughts?

Comment: This problem has resolved itself this morning after another reboot. I'm blaming it on a Windows Update or something weird performed by a rogue sys admin.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same problem earlier when trying to build from Visual Studio.

Tried running XCOPY manually and it was failing with the message *"xcopy' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"*

So I tried manually navigating to C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32 and executed XCOPY. It worked!

**Solution:**

1. Navigate to Control Panel -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment variables
2. When windows is first installed that variable is:
   *%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem*

   Put these at the beginning of the **PATH** variable and click OK twice.

You will need to restart running applications to apply the new path to them, not the system.

Comment: THIS SAVED MY LIFE! Visual Studio needed these three variables at the front in order to find things....THANK YOU dopplesoldner!

Comment: In my case, the problem occurred after installing a new Java version. That installtion put its path at the beginning of the `PATH` variable, causing the problems mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

This can only be one of two things: a problem with the PATH as seen from within your batch file, or a typo in the command being run (eg., XCOPY).

%systemroot% doesn't matter too much, as XCOPY and so forth are in the SYSTEM directory (on WinXP C:\Windows\System32), and %systemroot% is the Windows directory (one level higher - again, on XP C:\Windows).

Comment: That's what I would have thought but the batch file executes fine when I run it manually through the command line (even the VS command prompt)

Comment: There's one more case: In windows 8 my VS 2012 couldn't run applications in System32 even though it was run as administrator. I had to move the program out of System32.